# Javascript invalid argument in Dom. Style. Height

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting invalid argument exception on internet explorer for the following line.

```
document. getElementById('maindivJP' ). style. height = '90vh';
```

It is working while testing in visual studio. But when the build is deployed in url it is troubling.

Comment: Are you somehow talking about an IE version the dinosaurs have already been playing with (less than 9), or …?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Version 11.0.9600.19399

Comment: Hit F12 (Open Dev Tools), see Console and read the errors.

Comment: Invalid argument is the error I'm facing...in the developer tools!

Answer (score 0):

The code works well on my side. Please try to clear the browser cache and history, then retest your code. If still meet this error, try to use the following code:

```
document.getElementById('maindivJP').style.height = '900px';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('maindivJP').setAttribute("style", "height:90vh");
```